# Using Fluent NHibernate's AutoPersistenceModel but with eager loading in a single object

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, eager-loading

I'm using Fluent NHibernate in order to auto map my entities.

This is the code I'm using for the auto mapping:

```
new AutoPersistenceModel()
  .AddEntityAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Entity)))
  .Where(type => type.Namespace.Contains("Domain") && type.BaseType != null && type.BaseType.Name.StartsWith("DomainEntity") && type.BaseType.IsGenericType == true)
  .WithSetup(s => s.IsBaseType = (type => type.Name.StartsWith("DomainEntity") && type.IsGenericType == true))
  .ConventionDiscovery.Add(
      ConventionBuilder.Id.Always(x => x.GeneratedBy.Increment())
);
```

This works just fine. But now I need to have Eager Loading in one single object of my domain. Found [this answer](http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/6acc362331c93f6f?pli=1). But when I add the line `.ForTypesThatDeriveFrom<IEagerLoading>(map => map.Not.LazyLoad())` to the code and run it I get the following exception:

- *Error while trying to build the Mapping Document for IEagerLoading*

Notice that I'm using an interface (`IEagerLoading`) to mark the objects that I want eager load.

Can anyone help how to do this? Remember that I want to keep the auto mapping functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're hitting is that `ForTypesThatDeriveFrom<T>` is a bit misleadingly named, and that it really means `ForMappingsOf<T>`, so it's trying to find a `ClassMap<IEagerLoading>` which obviously doesn't exist.

I believe you should be able to handle this with a custom `IClassConvention`. This is off the top of my head, but should work:

```
public class EagerLoadingConvention : IClassConvention
{
  public bool Accept(IClassMap target)
  {
    return GetType().GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEagerLoading));
  }

  public void Apply(IClassMap target)
  {
    target.Not.LazyLoad();
  }
}
```